# What is included in the released .NET source code from Microsoft?

Tags: .net

General question about what Microsoft has released and how to get the code.

I've been looking for solid answers on exactly what source code Microsoft has released for the .NET open source or .NET CORE, as I believe they call it.

Specifically, I am acutely interested in the System.Windows namespace and the Dispatcher class therein.

Is there any official word from Microsoft in which they enumerate the various parts that have been and will be released?

Comment: It is a moving target.  But no, that namespace/class will never be part of it.  Too heavily dependent on closed-source native Windows components.  You can use the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Threading/Dispatcher.cs,078d6b27d9837a35) if you meant the WPF version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official list of what has been released is the source itself!

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src

Looks like nothing for System.Windows.

There's also a [list of what's coming](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx-progress/blob/master/src-diff/README.md), and there's nothing about System.Windows there either, so you may be out of luck, at least for the immediate future.